# Find specific anchor tag and replace data atribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, custom-data-attribute

I have following page structure

```
<div class="main">
   <article class="article">
   <!-- ... -->
      <div class="article-footer>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="article-play" data-play="3" data-src="http://..."></a></li>
            <li>...</li>
            <!-- ... -->
         </ul>
      </div>
   </article>

   <article class="article playing"> <!-- Notice Additional Class .playing
   <!-- ... -->
      <div class="article-footer>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="article-play" data-play="3" data-src="http://..."></a></li>
            <li>...</li>
            <!-- ... -->
         </ul>
      </div>
   </article>

   <!-- ... -->

</div>
```

So what I want to do is, inside this click function:

```
$(".audiojs .play-pause").click(function() {

  <!-- Code Here -->            
})
```

on click replace data attribute inside anchor tag with class `.article-play` that is inside article with class `.playing` from `data-play="3"` to `data-pause="4"` , However in a way that it checks that if there is `data-play="3"` than on click replace it with `data-pause="4"` else if there is `data-pause="4"` than replace it to `data-play="3"`

Comment: From the page source, I don't see any element that would satisfy the selector `".audiojs .play-pause"`.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do?  This feels like you've made the problem more complicated for yourself than it needs to be.

Comment: @Jack It is not presented her, I believe it is not important

Comment: @Alnitak I'm using icon-fonts with data attribute with them. I cant simply change value say data-icon="3" and data-icon="4" as I need them to be separate attributes for styling purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".audiojs .play-pause").click(function() {
    var element = $('.playing .article-play')
    var play = element.attr('data-play')
    var pause = element.attr('data-pause')
    if(play == '3'){
        element.removeAttr('data-play');
        element.attr("data-pause",'3');
    }else if(pause == '4'){
        element.removeAttr('data-pause');
        element.attr("data-play",'4');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work (un-tested):

```
var dataPlay = $(".playing a.article-play").data("play");
var dataPause = $(".playing a.article-play").data("pause");

if (dataPlay == "3") {
    $(".playing a.article-play").removeAttr("data-play").attr("data-pause", "4");
} else if (dataPause == "4") {
    $(".playing a.article-play").removeAttr("data-pause").attr("data-play", "3");
}
```

Comment: Seems to only work one way, removes data play and sets data pause, yet on another clicks nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $("article.playing a.article-play")
a.each(function(){
    var playAttr = $(this).attr("data-play")
    var pauseAttr = $(this).attr("data-pause")
    if(playAttr){
        if(playAttr == "4"){
            $(this).removeAttr("data-play");
            $(this).data("pause",3);
        }
    }
    if(pauseAttr){
        if(pauseAttr == "3"){
            $(this).removeAttr("data-pause");
            $(this).data("play",4);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can separate the method that handles `pause` from the method that handles `play`

**simplified HTML**

```
<div class="playing">
    <div id="output"></div> 

    <a href="#" class="article-play" data-play="4">click</a>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".playing").on("click", ".article-play[data-pause]", function () {
    $(this).removeAttr("data-pause");
    $(this).attr("data-play", 4);

    $("#output").text("playing 4");
});

$(".playing").on("click", ".article-play[data-play]", function () {
    $(this).removeAttr("data-play");
    $(this).attr("data-pause", 3);

    $("#output").text("pausing 3");
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjkQT/10/)

This answer is based on the answers I received to [the question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942551/find-specific-anchor-tag-and-replace-data-atribute-on-click#16942861) while trying to implement this solution