# jquery select element based on attribute added dynamically

Tags: jquery, selector, custom-data-attribute

I was trying to answer this question: [Find specific anchor tag and replace data atribute on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942551/find-specific-anchor-tag-and-replace-data-atribute-on-click#16942861) and I created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjkQT/2/)  which attempts to select an anchor element based on a data attribute.

I want to trap events on this anchor based on specific data attributes.

`<a href="#" class="article-play" data-play="4">click</a>`

**JS**

```
//this event only fires if 'data-pause' is initially specified in the anchor element
$(".article-play[data-pause]").on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("data-pause");
    $(this).attr("data-play",4);

    $("#output").text("playing 4");
});

//this event only fires if 'data-play' is initially specified in the anchor element
$(".article-play[data-play]").on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("data-play");
    $(this).attr("data-pause",3);

    $("#output").text("pausing 3");
});
```

Is this expected behavior?  A bug in jQuery?  Something else?

Comment: It's expected.  It's evaluating the selector before the attribute is added and therefore does not match to it.

Comment: I can't help thinking that the OP of the original question is doing this wrong...

Comment: @Cj S.  I thought `on` was meant to be a replacement for `live` which allowed us to bind to dynamic elements

Comment: try this way: http://jsfiddle.net/BjkQT/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your element is not in DOM at time you bind handler, you need to delegate event:

http://jsfiddle.net/BjkQT/8/

```
$(".article").on("click", ".article-play[data-pause]", function () {
    $(this).removeAttr("data-pause");
    $(this).attr("data-play", 4);

    $("#output").text("playing 4");
});

$(".article").on("click", ".article-play[data-play]", function () {
    $(this).removeAttr("data-play");
    $(this).attr("data-pause", 3);

    $("#output").text("pausing 3");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use delegation if you are dynamically changing the element

```
$('parentelement').on('click','.article-play[data-pause]',function(){
    $(this).removeAttr("data-pause");
    $(this).attr("data-play",4);

    $("#output").text("playing 4");
});

$('parentelement').on('click','.article-play[data-play]',function(){
    $(this).removeAttr("data-play");
    $(this).attr("data-pause",3);

    $("#output").text("pausing 3");
});
```

jQuery live documents the replacement for [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/#entry-longdesc)

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

It shows binding to the document as that's how live works - but it's better to bind the handler to a static parent element of the selector

You can read more about it here in the [jQuery .on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)